# Linespacing editor

Tags: texmaker, line-spacing, editors

I would like to change line-spacing in the editor (and not the document). I use TexMaker, on Windows 7 Enterprise. If this is even possible, do you know what I should do?

Comment: Hi, welcome. I can't immediately see an option for this in the Texmaker settings, but would switching to another editor be an option? In TeXstudio this is an easy change in the settings.